# How i can copy present month data as a previous month data in sql (I have provided example query with 3 records but how it works for many records)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So here is my question.

I have a table with 10 records (Date column says 2016-11-25 all the records) Now in next month another 10 records were been inserted now it holds 20 records with (Date column says 2016-11-25 10 records), (Date column says 2016-12-17 for 10 records) Now what i have to do is i have to make a copy all these 20 records to same table with date should be inserted as (END OF EACH MONTH) 2016-06-30 and 2016-07-31 like that. Please let me know if you still have questions

If you did not get this i have provided a small sql query that do same operation please go through that and let me know how i can do this please

--example--

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP1 (NAME VARCHAR(100), PLACE VARCHAR(100), [DATE] VARCHAR (100));
INSERT INTO #TEMP1 VALUES ('A','USA', '2016-10-16') ,('B','UK', '2016-11-18') ,('C','ASIA', '2016-11-12');
SELECT * FROM #TEMP1
```

--NOW I NEED TO INSERT SAME ROWS AS BUT IT'S DATE SHOULD BE WITH JUNE, JULY, AUG, SEP

--HERE ARE RESULTS SHOULD BE IN TEMP1 (TEMP2 RESULTS)

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP2 (NAME VARCHAR(100), PLACE VARCHAR(100), [DATE] VARCHAR (100))

INSERT INTO #TEMP2 VALUES 
('A','USA', '2016-06-30') ,('B','UK', '2016-06-30') ,('C','ASIA', '2016-06-30') 
---JUNE 
,('A','USA', '2016-07-31') ,('B','UK', '2016-07-31') ,('C','ASIA', '2016-07-31') 
---JULY 
,('A','USA', '2016-08-31') ,('B','UK', '2016-08-31') ,('C','ASIA', '2016-08-31') 
--- AUG 
,('A','USA', '2016-09-30') ,('B','UK', '2016-09-30') ,('C','ASIA', '2016-09-30') 
--- SEP 
,('A','USA', '2016-10-31') ,('B','UK', '2016-10-31') ,('C','ASIA', '2016-10-31') 
--- OCT 
,('A','USA', '2016-11-30') ,('B','UK', '2016-11-30') ,('C','ASIA', '2016-11-30') 
--- NOV 
,('A','USA', '2016-12-31') ,('B','UK', '2016-12-31') ,('C','ASIA', '2016-12-31')
 --- DEC

SELECT * FROM #TEMP2
```

--RESULTS HAVE TO BE LIKE #TEMP2

--WHEN EVER THERE IS NEW RECORD INSERTED INTO THIS TABLE IT HAS TO COPY FROM JUNE TO THIS MONTH

Comment: If you highlight a code segment and press the Code Sample button (above the text entry area) then it will format the code sample into a more readable format.

Comment: In SQL Server 2012 and above, the [`EOMONTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) function exists. This also seems very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very redundant and somewhat pointless. More redundant than the amount of times I used very in the previous sentence. You shouldn't really be storing this data in a table, you should be putting it in, say, a view or a stored procedure.

Comment: I wouldn't say creating a calendar table (this is a rudimentary start to it) is redundant, though if we understood the final purpose we might find it is.

Comment: Are you sure that the rows with the end-of-month dates should be in the same table as the rows with the original records?  Is this code to be run just once, or will you wish to generate this end-of-month data in subsequent months?

Comment: Don't store dates as strings. Ever. Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).

Comment: It needs to run every day @toonice.
If any one has solution please let me know